# Annual letter from my friend

Tags: word, story, wordle

I have a friend who sends me a letter once a year. It's usually pretty clear what they're trying to say, but this year they sent me a weird block of squares, and I have no idea what it means. What's really weird is that it was addressed to Ethan Green - that's not my surname!

```
⬜⬜⬜  
⬜⬜⬜  
⬜⬜⬛⬛  
⬛⬜⬛⬛  
⬛⬜⬜⬜⬛
```

What is my friend trying to say?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe he's trying to say:

> HAPPY
> BIRTH
> DAY
> TO
> YOU
> ETHAN

solved by:

> Putting 'Ethan' in the Green squares, then working with messages what could be sent once a year

Comment: Perfect! Congrats